# removing the borders of the navbar's button in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a webpage and let's say I've got this navbar: (Courtesy [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/))

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"> 
   <div class="navbar-header"> 
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"  
         data-target="#example-navbar-collapse"> 
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
         <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
         <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button> 
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TutorialsPoint</a> 
   </div> 
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse"> 
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
         <li class="active"><a href="#">iOS</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">SVN</a></li> 
         <li class="dropdown"> 
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
               Java <b class="caret"></b> 
            </a> 
            <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
               <li><a href="#">jmeter</a></li> 
               <li><a href="#">EJB</a></li> 
               <li><a href="#">Jasper Report</a></li> 
               <li class="divider"></li> 
               <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li> 
               <li class="divider"></li> 
               <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li> 
            </ul> 
         </li> 
      </ul> 
   </div> 
</nav>
```

This creates borders like this:
[image: borders!]
codepen.io/aravind-forever/pen/WGQXzL

I want to remove the borders from both the `button` and the `nav`. How do I do this? I've tried `border: none` but that does not work.

*Merci d'avance!*

Answer (score 2):

Note sure why you're having difficulty...

`.navbar.navbar-default, .navbar button.navbar-toggle { border: none; }`

See it in a fiddle here: **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/svwptu7v/)**

```css
.navbar.navbar-default, .navbar button.navbar-toggle { border: none; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div style="height: 40px;" title="just to move it down a little in snippet"></div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"> 
   <div class="navbar-header"> 
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"  
         data-target="#example-navbar-collapse"> 
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
         <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
         <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button> 
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TutorialsPoint</a> 
   </div> 
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse"> 
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
         <li class="active"><a href="#">iOS</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">SVN</a></li> 
         <li class="dropdown"> 
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
               Java <b class="caret"></b> 
            </a> 
            <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
               <li><a href="#">jmeter</a></li> 
               <li><a href="#">EJB</a></li> 
               <li><a href="#">Jasper Report</a></li> 
               <li class="divider"></li> 
               <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li> 
               <li class="divider"></li> 
               <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li> 
            </ul> 
         </li> 
      </ul> 
   </div> 
</nav>
```

Comment: Didi you see the fiddle or snippet above? Clearly it works.

Comment: @Scott send you a link to fiddle where it works, so if it doesn't work for you can check if you're linking to the correct css or just clear browser's cache.

Comment: There's no cache.. I set up the fiddle... nothing cached. And it links to the bootstrap CSS CDN. Note for the snippet here, I had to be more specific with the CSS selectors.. but it still works.

Comment: so, any idea it does not work for me? I'm not using the cdn, i'm using a downloaded file, is that the problem then?

Comment: No idea.. I can't see your css.

Answer (score 0):

Lets keep it simple.

For *nav*, You can use:

```
.navbar-default{
    border:0px;
}
```

For *button*, You can use:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle{
    border:0px;
}
```

Or just copy the code below to your CSS file:

```
.navbar-default, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle{
    border:0px;
}
```

If nothing works, Try adding `!important` at the of `0px`

Answer (score 0):

you may call your style sheets in wrong order,
You can inline styling [ style="border: none;" ] for **nav** element and **button** element as beloved.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" style="border: none;"> 
   <div class="navbar-header"> 
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"  
         data-target="#example-navbar-collapse" style="border: none;"> 
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
         <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
         <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button> 
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TutorialsPoint</a> 
   </div> 
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse"> 
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
         <li class="active"><a href="#">iOS</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">SVN</a></li> 
         <li class="dropdown"> 
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
               Java <b class="caret"></b> 
            </a> 
            <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
               <li><a href="#">jmeter</a></li> 
               <li><a href="#">EJB</a></li> 
               <li><a href="#">Jasper Report</a></li> 
               <li class="divider"></li> 
               <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li> 
               <li class="divider"></li> 
               <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li> 
            </ul> 
         </li> 
      </ul> 
   </div> 
</nav>
```